# Facing some confusions in pointer in C Language

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

What is the difference between `int* ptr(int, int)` and `int (*ptr)(int, int)`??

Please explain me it details that's what's happening here.

Comment: The first is a function named `ptr` that returns a pointer to an `int`, and `ptr` is not a variable. In the second `ptr` is a variable which points to a function that returns an `int`, in other words is a variable that contains the address of a function of that type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1.

```
 int* ptr(int, int)
```

`ptr` is a function which takes two `int` arguments and returns a pointer to `int`.

#### 2.

```
 int (*ptr)(int, int)
```

`ptr` is a pointer to a function which takes two `int` arguments and returns an `int`.

---

The latter makes sense if you f.e. have several optional functions available but want to choose a specific one by a particular matching condition. Then you build up an array of function pointers and pick the desired function pointer. But notice that the pointed function here is a a little bit different then the one at the first example as it is returning an `int`, not a pointer to an `int`.

If the function pointed to should be equivalent to the first form with returning a pointer to `int` you need to do:

```
 int* (*ptr)(int, int)
```

---

If you only have one function to go with you don´t need to addressing it via a pointer and rather use the first form.

If you want to learn more about function pointers, here is a link to a dedicated SO question:

[How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Comment: can you please elaborate it little bit more.

Comment: @MolybdenumOxide I think the answers under this question explain it at its best: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work

Comment: No, pls explain or give me some reference regarding this.

Comment: @MolybdenumOxide That is a huge topic on its own. I recommend you to read a good C starting book first. F.e. this one: https://kremlin.cc/k&r.pdf

Comment: @MolybdenumOxide [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) - Here you can find a great source of collected knowledge.